# Reactive updates when query is filtered by another query

Tags: meteor

I just started using meteor today and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a query that is being run inside of a publish function, but this query is filtered by the result of another query.

In short, when I add a document to the database that is being published (CollectionTwo) it works as I would expect, but when I make my change in the database that is being used to filter (CollectionOne), meteor doesn't behave reactively.

```
CollectionOne = new Meteor.Collection("one")
CollectionTwo = new Meteor.Collection("two")

Meteor.publish("items", ->
  not_hidden = CollectionOne.find().fetch()
  return CollectionTwo.find( _id: {'$in':( t.my_id for t in not_hidden )} )
)
```

Meanwhile, on the client...

```
CollectionOne = new Meteor.Collection("one")
CollectionTwo = new Meteor.Collection("two")

Meteor.subscribe("items")

_.extend( Template.items,
  items: ->
    not_hidden = CollectionOne.find().fetch()
    return CollectionTwo.find( _id: {'$in':( t.my_id for t in not_hidden )} )
)
```

Any ideas what the appropriate solution might be?

Comment: If you want a subscription to behave reactively you have to use Meteor.autosubscribe http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_autosubscribe

Comment: @lashleigh I was under the impression that autosubscribe only works when session variable parameters change. Anyway, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have a collection called 'items' so subscribing to it shouldn't actually do anything. I'm pretty sure the subscribe name needs to map to the name of an actual collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reactivity doesn't work that way inside `Meteor.publish` on the server.  Meteor won't recalculate the `CollectionTwo.find` query when the contents of `CollectionOne` changes.

To implement what you want, manage the publish by hand, instead of just returning a Cursor.  You'll need to use `observe`inside your publish function to watch for changes on `CollectionOne`, and then manually call `this.set` and `this.unset` to push changes down to the client.  There's an example of this technique in the [publish documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish).  The example only looks at one collection, but you can extend the idea to a nested set of observes.

We're going to work on sugar to make this sort of pattern easier to implement.

Comment: Sadly there's not really anything like this in the manual :( - set and unset are completely undocumented, is there a way to add an example of such a pattern? Right now I find myself having to add arbitrary fields to my collections to simulate joins.

Comment: Reactivity works now with the [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package (I am one of authors).

Answer (score 4):

Until there's a better pattern for this in core meteor these two atmosphere packages solve the problem:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/server-deps

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reactive-publish

Install the second package with meteorite, use "Meteor.reactivePublish" instead of "Meteor.publish" and it will automatically update when the results of any queries with the option {"reactive": true} change.

This example from the readme will publish precisely those items which the user's team can see, and will update when either the user changes team or the team's visible items change.

```
Meteor.reactivePublish(null, function() {
  if (this.userId) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}, {reactive: true});
    if (user.team) {
      var team = Collections.teams.findOne({_id: user.team}, {reactive: true});
      var visibleItems = _.compact(team.visibleItems);
      return Collections.items.find({_id: {$in: visibleItems}});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a great approach. There is an [rewritten package](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) now available. BTW, you also have to limit which fields you are interested in `Meteor.users`, otherwise your reactive publish will rerun every time any field changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package (I am one of authors):

```
Meteor.publish "items", ->
  @autorun (computation) =>
    not_hidden = CollectionOne.find({}, {fields: my_id: 1}).fetch()
    CollectionTwo.find _id: $in: _.pluck not_hidden, 'my_id'
```

The important thing is to limit queried fields from `CollectionOne` to only `my_id`, otherwise `autorun` will be rerun on any field change in `CollectionOne` documents, not just `my_id`.