# How to deal with dynamic subscriptions in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a publication whose scope depends on a element property from another collection. Basically it looks like this on the server:

```
Meteor.publish('kids', function (parent) {
    return Kids.find({ _id: { $in: parent.childrenIds } });
}
```

In the example above `parent.childrenIds` is an array containing the _id's of all the kids that are children of the parent. This works fine until I want to add a new child to the parent:

```
newKidId = Kids.insert({ name: 'Joe' });
Parents.update({ _id: parentId }, { $push: { childrenIds: newKidId } });
```

This works *on the server* for the `Kids` collection (i.e., the new kid is added) and it updates the parent's `childrenIds` array with the `newKidId`. BUT it does not update the above 'kids' publication (the cursor is not updated/modified). As a result, the *client*'s `Kids` collection is not updated (and it looks like the change to `Kids` is rolled back on the client).

When the client refreshes, all publications are stopped/restarted and the new kid (Joe) is finally published to the client.

Is there a way to avoid refreshing the client and forcing the re-publication of the `Kids` collection (ideally only sending the new kid Joe to the client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days you can simply use [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package (I am one of authors):

```
Meteor.publish('kids', function (parentId) {
    this.autorun(function (computation) {
        var parent = Parents.findOne(parentId, {fields: {childrenIds: 1}});
        return Kids.find({_id: {$in: parent.childrenIds}});
    });
}
```

It is important to limit `Parents`' query fields only to `childrenIds` so that `autorun` does not rerun for any other changes to `Parents` document.

Answer (score 7):

One of the things that is often misunderstood in Meteor is that **there is no reactivity on the server**.  Dynamic descriptions need to be handled by `Deps.autorun` blocks on the client.  To do this, first make sure you are not including the autopublish package by using this command in project directory:

```
$ meteor remove autopublish
```

Second, set up an autorun block **on the client** like:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('parents');

  Deps.autorun(function() {
    parent = Parents.findOne();
    if (!parent) return;
    Meteor.subscribe('kids', parent);
  });
});
```

This will tear down and set up subscriptions as the parent object changes.

You can see a full working example at https://gist.github.com/jagill/5473599 .

Comment: Thanks jagill for this Gist - it works indeed. Now, your server code does rely on the client sending the correct `parent` object to determine what are the (latest) keys in `parent.childrenIds`. This is a security hole. How would you check on the server that `parent` has indeed been updated with that particular kid? I try passing `parent._id` (and adapting the Kids publication), but it breaks the intended behaviour (have a look at https://gist.github.com/jbmoens/5476431 - I have commented my edits)

Comment: That's a separate question, which I'd be happy to answer.  But it's best posted as a new question, with this question accepted/closed.

Comment: Done - look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274226/how-to-make-dynamic-subscriptions-secure-in-meteor)

Answer (score 1):

In meantime there were quite some packages made to deal with reactive publish functions. I am an author of [meteor-related](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-related), and at the end of the package's README I compare my package with few other packages:

- [meteor-reactive-publish](https://github.com/Diggsey/meteor-reactive-publish)
- [meteor-publish-with-relations](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-publish-with-relations)
- [meteor-smart-publish](https://github.com/yeputons/meteor-smart-publish)
- [reywood:publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite)
- [copleyjk:simple-publish](https://github.com/copleykj/meteor-simple-publish)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use observe in the publish function if a published query relies on a second query.  Deps.autorun on the client is not necessary.

See discussions on  [Meteor server reactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717352/meteor-server-reactivity) and [Reactive updates when query is filtered by another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524482/reactive-updates-when-query-is-filtered-by-another-query?rq=1).

This is some code based on http://docs.meteor.com 'counts-by-room' example.

```
Meteor.publish( "kids", function(parent_id){
  var self = this;

  Parents.find({_id: parent_id}, { childrenIds: 1 }).observe({
    added: function (document){
    document.childrenIds.forEach( function(kidId){
      self.added("kids", kidId, Kids.findOne( { _id: kidId}, {name: 1, _id: 1} ));
      });
    },

    removed: function (oldDocument){
      oldDocument.childrenIds.forEach( function(kidId){
        self.removed("kids", kidId, Kids.findOne( { _id: kidId}, {name: 1, _id: 1} ));
        });
    },

    changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument){
      var oldLength = oldDocument.childrenIds.length;
      var newLength = newDocument.childrenIds.length;
        if (newLength > oldLength){
          self.added("kids", 
                      newDocument.childrenIds[newLength-1], 
                      Kids.findOne( { _id: newDocument.childrenIds[newLength-1] }, {name:1, _id:1}) );
        }
        else{
          self.removed("kids", 
                        oldDocument.childrenIds[oldLength-1], 
                        Kids.findOne( { _id: oldDocument.childrenIds[oldLength-1] }, {name:1, _id:1}) );
        }
      }
   });

   self.ready();      
});
```