# How to make dynamic subscriptions secure in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

This question builds on a previous one (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252077/how-to-deal-with-dynamic-subscriptions-in-meteor/)).

The dynamic subscription is set up with this code (slightly modified from the previous question):

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('parents');

  Deps.autorun(function() {
    parent = Parents.findOne({ _id: Session.get('parentId') });
    if (!parent) return;
    Meteor.subscribe('kids', parent);
  });
});
```

The problem is that the server side must trust the `parent` object that is passed by the client. Ideally, one would want to pass only the `_id` of the parent object like this:

```
  Deps.autorun(function() {
    parentId = Session.get('parentId');
    if (!parentId) return;
    Meteor.subscribe('kids', parentId);
  });
```

But, in this case, the dynamic subscription behavior breaks (e.g., the `kids` collection is not updated on the client when the parent's children array is updated).

Why is `Session.get('parentId')` less reactive than `Parents.findOne({ _id: Session.get('parentId') })`, or has this to do with `Meteor.subscribe('kids', parent)` vs. `Meteor.subscribe('kids', parentId)`?

What would be the best pattern to coding this right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is the following:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    parent = Parents.findOne({ _id: Session.get('parentId') }, {fields: {_id: 1}});
    if (!parent) return;
    Meteor.subscribe('kids', parent._id);
});
```

However, this still isn't exactly secure; it's just checking the `Parents` collection to make sure the referenced Session variable exists before attempting to subscribe to it - and this depends on the `parents` subscription. If you want it to be properly secured, you'll want to not send any parents over on the `parent` subscription to the client, if the client shouldn't be able to see them.